# Azure is giving starting application error

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot, publishing

I have created an echo bot from echo bot builder sdk4 as instructed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

It works fine locally. But when I publish it, it gives the following error.
"An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Core 4.6.26919.02 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.1.1-rtm-30846    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?"

I don't know what is wrong. My .NET Core version is 2.1.

Comment: Maybe this post http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-How-to-Fix-Error-An-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application-in-ASPNET-Core.aspx relevant with your error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all set log folder on the Azure server and find issue with more details or add `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = true`in app settings of your app. then restart

**Extra** :There is a nice set of troubleshooting and analysis tools for use with Microsoft Azure Web Apps (formerlly Web Sites) called KUDU.  Information about that tool set can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/).

It is useful for capturing a memory dump , deployment logs, viewing configuration parameters and much

Answer (score 1):

You can **enable logging** to see whats happening:

- Go to the Kudu environment (https://YOURSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net)
- On the top menu, select Debug console -> PowerShell
- Navigate to site
  -> wwwroot and open the web.config
- Set the **stdoutLogEnabled** attribute to true and save the file.
- Create a folder named logs (see stdoutLogFile) next to the web.config

Read more here: [Determine whats wrong with your Azure Web / API App deployment](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/05/determine-whats-wrong-with-azure-web-app-deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created same bot from Azure. Echo bot as it asked me. Since, it is made on Azure, it has all other files, like web.config. This one can be downloaded. Then, I can amend it. After that, I can publish it again. So, all is fine in that way. I also got the response from Microsoft team. Check it here. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/494